# regex check closed brackets

Tags: regex

I need help with regex to check brackets in text. 
good:

```
{{var1}} dsfsd {{var2}}
```

bad:

```
{{var {{dsfsdf}}
var}} {{dsfsdf}}
{{var1}} {{var2 {{var3}}
{{var1}} var2}} {{var3}}
{{var1}} {{var2}} var3}}
{{var1}} {{var2}} {{var3
```

I tried

```
const condition1 = "(\{\{([^}]*)\}(?!\}))";
                const condition2 = "((?<!\{)\{([^{]*)\}\})";
                const condition3 = "^[^\{\r\n]*\}.*?$";
                const condition4 = "^.*?\{(?!.*?\})[^}]*$";
                const regExp =  new RegExp(condition1+"|"+condition2+"|"+condition4);
```

Comment: Try `/^(?:[^{}]|{{\w+}})+$/.test(condition1)`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbyPWR/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try `(?s){{(?:(?>(?!{{|}}).)|(?R))*}}`

Comment: It's invalid target for quantifier

Comment: What regex engine

Comment: if this regex works to match, use it to delete the "good". Any {{ or }} left in string invalidates the string.

Comment: JS cannt do nest brakt match